# getting error jar not present at run time

Tags: java, docker

Getting error while running an image:

> C:\Users\10649404\Desktop\spring-boot-websocket-chat-demo>docker run
>   -p 5000:8080 ok 2019-04-29 07:10:58.660 INFO  org.glowroot - Glowroot version: 0.10.12, built 2018-06-22 00:08:17 +0000 2019-04-29
>   07:10:58.673 INFO  org.glowroot - Java version: 1.8.0_201

This is the jar file I am not getting. It says that  missing `lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar`, even though it is present at the location.

```
2019-04-29 07:10:58.682 ERROR org.glowroot - missing lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar
2019-04-29 07:10:58.688 ERROR org.glowroot - Glowroot not started: org.glowroot.agent.embedded.init.EmbeddedGlowrootAgentInitFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glowroot.agent.embedded.init.EmbeddedGlowrootAgentInitFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.glowroot.agent.MainEntryPoint.createGlowrootAgentInit(MainEntryPoint.java:311)
        at org.glowroot.agent.MainEntryPoint.start(MainEntryPoint.java:273)
        at org.glowroot.agent.MainEntryPoint.premain(MainEntryPoint.java:173)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glowroot.agent.AgentPremain.premain(AgentPremain.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
```

This is my docker file content:

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp

VOLUME /tmp
# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /opt/glowroot/glowroot.jar glowroot.jar
ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar  glowroot-embedded-collector.jar

ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-central-collector-https-linux.jar  glowroot-central-collector-https-linux.jar
ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-central-collector-https-osx.jar  glowroot-central-collector-https-osx.jar
ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-central-collector-https-windows.jar  
glowroot-central-collector-https-windows.jar
    COPY /opt/glowroot/ /opt/glowroot/ 
    # The application's jar file
    ARG JAR_FILE=target/websocket-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ARG OK=/opt/glowroot/glowroot.jar
    # Add the application's jar to the container
    ADD ${JAR_FILE} websocket-demo.jar
    #ADD ${OK} glowroot.jar
    # Run the jar file 

CMD ["java", "-javaagent:/glowroot.jar","-Dglowroot.agent.id=Docker","-jar", "/websocket-demo.jar"]
```

Please let me know the issue. jar is present at `lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar`

Comment: What makes you think that a Java error message is in any way related to Docker?

Comment: Add the jar to the classpath ```CMD ["java","-cp","glowroot-embedded-collector.jar", "-javaagent:/glowroot.jar","-Dglowroot.agent.id=Docker","-jar", "/websocket-demo.jar"]```. Note glowroot-embedded-collector.jar not inside lib directory as I couldn't find any workdir being created so add it accordingly.

Comment: @Barath -cp does not work when running an executable jar.

Comment: @Gimby you are right my bad I missed the fact that it will get ignored. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you have:

```
ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar  glowroot-embedded-collector.jar
```

This copies the jar file in the root so it's available at: /glowroot-embedded-collector.jar

When you say that lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar is available, do you mean on host or inside the container? Because based on your Dockerfile I don't think it can be present inside the container.

Maybe try to change the ADD statement this way:

```
ADD /opt/glowroot/lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar  lib/glowroot-embedded-collector.jar
```